# Hyperledger Fabric: timeout when sending proposal to peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem with fabric 1.4 while using fabric-gateway-java. Sometimes, it throw TimeoutException when sending proposal to peers. In most cases, it works well. Can anyone help? thanks!
Here is the error log.

```
2020-09-03 10:02:34,202 [ERROR]--org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel 4451 -- Channel 
Channel{id:1,name: mychannel} sending proposal with transaction
e1d7313d8f8fc09fbae9a3ac2027bbf33ba3714c028a609f26380a4b0810466e to 
Peer{ id: 6, name: peer1.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, 
url:grpcs://192.168.1.1:7051, mspid: Org1MSP} failed because of 
timeout(35000 milliseconds) expiration
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:432)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:4434)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposal(Channel.java:4358)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendTransactionProposal(Channel.java:3908)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I do not have any direct solution for your problem but I try to help you.

The problem is happened in "fabric-sdk-java" not in "fabric-gateway-java".
More specifically :

```
catch (TimeoutException e) {
            message = format("Channel %s sending proposal with transaction %s to %s failed because of timeout(%d milliseconds) expiration",
                    toString(), txID, peerName, transactionContext.getProposalWaitTime());
            logger.error(message, e);
        }
```

Links: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/Channel.java

For "fabric-sdk-java" you may follow this:

You may increase your setProposalWaitTime.

```
setProposalWaitTime

public void setProposalWaitTime(long proposalWaitTime)

Sets the timeout for a single proposal request to endorser in milliseconds.

Parameters:
    proposalWaitTime - the timeout for a single proposal request to endorser in milliseconds
```

Links: https://javadoc.io/static/org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java/fabric-sdk-java/2.2.0/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/TransactionRequest.html#setProposalWaitTime-long-

So your code may look something like that:

```
        TransactionProposalRequest request = fabClient.getInstance().newTransactionProposalRequest();
        ChaincodeID ccid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName(Config.CHAINCODE_1_NAME).build();
        request.setChaincodeID(ccid);
        request.setFcn("createCar");
        String[] arguments = { "CAR1", "Chevy", "Volt", "Red", "Nick" };
        request.setArgs(arguments);
        request.setProposalWaitTime(4000);
```

For "fabric-gateway-java" you may follow this:

TimeoutException - If the transaction was successfully submitted to the orderer but timed out before a commit event was received from peers.

Links: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/master/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/Contract.html#createTransaction-java.lang.String-

So you may increase setCommitTimeout.

setCommitTimeout -Set the maximum length of time to wait for commit events to be received after submitting a transaction to the orderer.

Transaction setCommitTimeout(long timeout,
TimeUnit timeUnit)

Parameters:

timeout - the maximum time to wait.

timeUnit - the time unit of the timeout argument.

Returns:
this transaction object to allow method chaining.

Links: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/master/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/Transaction.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.However the transaction have not send to orderer. It time out when I create the transaction and send to the endorsing peers. It happened in the class Channel.Java. ( the mothod is  private Collection<ProposalResponse> sendProposalToPeers(Collection<Peer> peers,
                                                             SignedProposal signedProposal,
                                                             TransactionContext transactionContext) throws InvalidArgumentException, ProposalException ) And the default timeout is 35000ms, I think it is enough.

Comment: Actually I'm sorry that I don't have the actual solution and the line "fabric-gateway-java" in question section, also confused me.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I am using debug log for more information, but I still do not solve it.